# SpringBootApp issue with package

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

in images below I show you my SpringBoot project configuration by start.spring.io/. I choose (for now) two dependency (spring dev tools and spring web), now I run the application but I got this error. What is the error?

[image]

[image]

Maven version installe 3.9.3
Java openjdk 17
intellij 2023.1.4 community edition

Thanks guys

Comment: [Re-import](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start) the project and make sure it downloads all the dependencies, try running from the command line Maven via `mvn spring-boot:run`.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Hi, I reimported the project and tried to run the command but I get this error: "Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ... /home/myfolder/.m2/settings.xml, line 15, column 4".

Comment: Try deleting settings.xml file.

Comment: @CrazyCoder ok I deleted the settings.xml file and now? Re-run the command?

Comment: Yes, I would do that.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I get this error : "Could not create local repository at /home/myfolder/.m2/repository -> [Help 1]"

Comment: I also deleted the .m2 folder and re-run the command but the build failed: "Could not find goal 'ru' in plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.1.1 among available goals build-image, build-image-no-fork, build-info, help, process-aot, process-test-aot, repackage, run, start, stop, test-run -> [Help 1]"

Comment: @CrazyCoder I fix it, I did maven clean and reload all maven project via intellij and the errors go away and the application run successfully!. Thanks you so much.

Comment: Close the project in intellij. Close intelliJ ... delete the `.idea` directory and start IDEA new an reimport the project...That is not related to Maven... It's an IntelliJ issue...